# Redirecting User after Stripe Payment Node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const stripe = require('stripe')(keys.stripeSecretKey);

module.exports = app => {
  app.post('/api/stripe', async(req, res) => {
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: 6000,
      currency: 'eur',
      description: 'Boyle Celtic Registration 20/21',
      source: req.body.id,
    });
    console.log(charge);
    res.redirect('/confirmation');
  });
};
```

This is my `billingRoute` on my server side and I am trying to redirect the user to my confirmation page that I have created with React. But keep getting a `404` get error even though the route exists. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your "/confirmation" route hanlder ?

Comment: necessary imports just too long to put in for the comments

class App extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
   
    render(){
        return(
                <BrowserRouter>
      
                        <Route exact path="/confirmation" component={ConfirmationPage} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
       
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null,actions)(App)

thats the only place i have the route setup

Comment: just edit your post...

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from '../actions';
import Header from './Header';
import Landing from './Landing';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import regFormNew from './regForm/RegFormNew';
import ConfirmationPage from './ConfirmationPage';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
   
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <div className="container">
                        <Header />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                        <Route exact path="/form" component={Dashboard} />
                        <Route exact path="/form/new" component={regFormNew} />
                        <Route exact path="/confirmation" component={ConfirmationPage} />
                    </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
       
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

this is where i put my route for the confirmation page

Comment: Then i have authRoute file just for login with google